# What are the potential deadlocks when converting from MYISAM to InnoDb?

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I keep reading that when you convert your database from MYISAM storage engine over to InnoDb engine you must add support for deadlocks in your application code. I need to know:

1. What are these deadlocks?
2. How do we add the capability to handle them in our application code once we convert the database over to InnoDb?

Any more information on the subject is much appreciated.

Comment: one thing is you don't have full text support for your MYISAM tables

Comment: A deadlock can only happend in transactions. If you are not going to use them, you do not have nothing to worry about.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Comment: @eversor "Application should be ready to work with Innodb, for example be ready to deal with deadlocks which can happen with Innodb even if you do not use transactions, but which are not existent with MyISAM." - Peter Zaitsev, http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/01/12/should-you-move-from-myisam-to-innodb/